# Display wrong information with the good row value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with the code below. In fact, it's supposed to show the information of a table, where the MomentEvent value match with the row requested. The only problem, is that sometimes, it show the information of a complete diffrent row! And I don't have any idea why! Does the problem come from my code?

And in my table, the information are placed in order, so they are always added one after an other.

```
<?php
include('base.php');
?>


<?php
if(isset($_GET['MomentEvent']))
{
     $MomentEvent = intval($_GET['MomentEvent']);
     $dn = mysql_query("select Ordre, Confidentialite, ID, TitreEvent, DescriptionEvent, LieuEvent from users_event where MomentEvent=$MomentEvent");
     if(mysql_num_rows($dn)>0)
     {
             $dnn = mysql_fetch_array($dn);
?>
This is the profile of "<?php echo htmlentities($dnn['TitreEvent']); ?>" :
<table style="width:500px;">

      <tr><td>

<?php
if($dnn['avatar']!='')
     {
     echo '<img src="'.htmlentities($dnn['avatar'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'" alt="Avatar"    style="max-width:100px;max-height:100px;" />';
     }
else
{
     echo 'This user dont have an avatar.';
}
 ?>

</td>
     <td class="left"><h1><?php echo ($dnn['TitreEvent']); ?></h1>
     Email: <?php echo htmlentities($dnn['DescriptionEvent']); ?><br />
     <a href=*****.php>Retour.</a>
      </tr>
</table>
 <?php
     }
     else
     {
             echo 'Sorry, any event found';
     }
}
 else
{
     echo 'The user ID is not defined.';
 }
 ?>
                       </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: looks like your html is wrong in several places, validate it: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: the problem isn't more from the php?

Comment: what variable is not showing exact ?

Comment: TitreEvent and DescriptionEvent

Comment: you sure that MomentEvent is right ?

Comment: Yes, because most of the pages are loaded with the correct information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now all works fine with these changes:

```
$MomentEvent = $_GET['MomentEvent'];
$sql = "select ID, TitreEvent, DescriptionEvent, LieuEvent from users_event where MomentEvent='$MomentEvent'"; 
$dn = mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have missed `</td>` in your code.

and use `echo $dnn['TitreEvent'];` without parenthesis

try this

```
      <td class="left"><h1><?php echo $dnn['TitreEvent']; ?></h1>
 Email: <?php echo htmlentities($dnn['DescriptionEvent']); ?><br />
 <a href=*****.php>Retour.</a>
     </td>
       ^^----you missed this
```

EDIT:

Ithink you have many result returned from your sql and you need to specify more in your query .

like that

```
    where MomentEvent=$MomentEvent AND user = $theUser
```

Comment: It gives the following error: Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: :) `user = $theUser` they were just a suggest from me , you should use your column and your variable .